# How can I write the test cases for Lombok annotation

Tags: java, junit, mockito, lombok, testcase

**How can I write the test cases for Lombok annotation?**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ABC{
    
    private String status;
    private String errorCode;
    private String message;
    private String id;
    private Long orderNumber;
    private Long lineId;
}
//writing testcases for above class 
@Test
    public void testupdate_1()throws Exception{
        
    
    ABC result=new ABC();
    result.setStatus("");
    result.setErrorCode("");
    result.setMessage("");
    result.setId("");
    result.setOrderNumber(123l);
    result.setLineId(12l);;
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals("", result.getStatus());
    assertEquals("", result.getErrorCode());
    assertEquals("", result.getMessage());
    assertEquals("", result.getId());
    assertEquals(Long.valueOf(123l), result.getOrderNumber());
    assertEquals(Long.valueOf(12l), result.getLineId());
    
    }
```

even I tried this but code coverage is showing very less. Please, anyone can help me to find correct answer for this.

Answer (score 4):

Lombok author here: You don't.

You don't write test code to test that the inner workings of hibernate work correctly either; it's hibernate's job to test that. You don't test whether java's `switch` statement does what the spec says it does; it's team OpenJDK (the authors of `javac`)'s job to test that.

If you're chasing 100% code coverage by your tests, configure your code coverage tool to exclude lombok-generated code.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing only all args constructor. You can add test for no args constructor like:

```
    @Test
    public void testABC() {
        ABC abc = new ABC();
        assertNotNull(abc); 
    }
```